# How to pass JSON data to d3? The JSON data resides on an local host url "/table"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I first tried to get an ajax call to get the JSON data into a variable:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var js;
var url = "/table";
$.getJSON(url,
    function(data) {
        js = data;
        $("div").html(js);
    }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to check if the data has been properly loaded; I found out that it wasn't. 
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and D3: just use [d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json). Also, where is the extension in that URL?

Comment: I've rendered that JSON object in an HTML page from my local app. This is another HTML file in the same app trying to read data from there. 

I think the extension need not be specified?

Comment: And, my objective here in using jquery is just to get the JSON data so I can load it in d3 for charts. Is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: *"Is there a more direct way to do this?"*... please click the link I shared.

Comment: Thanks, @GerardoFurtado. That was a lot easier than I had thought.